"the rich" — The adjective “rich” is a fused modifier-head AdjP, and “the rich” is a fused modifier-head NP. — Is this parse correct?
the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 529:

from the passage above, I'm drawing the following conclusion:

(1) the rich
The adjective “rich” in (1) is a fused modifier-head AdjP.


the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", pages 518-519:

(2) Peter the Great
“The Great” in (2) is a fused modifier-head NP.


I'm combining the information from (1) and (2) and getting:
(1) the rich
The adjective “rich” is a fused modifier-head AdjP.
“The rich” is a fused modifier-head NP. — Is this correct?
(2) Peter the Great
The adjective “Great” is a fused modifier-head AdjP. — Is this correct?
“The Great” is a fused modifier-head NP.

Update:
I'm asking it because I've seen the term "fused modifier-head AdjP" for the first time and I want to know whether I've understood it correctly or not.

If you follow the reference to Ch. 5, §9.3, I think you’ll find the answer (which I believe is yes) on  p. 417:

9.3 Fusion of internal modifier and head. . . (f) Modifier-heads with
special interpretations . . .[29]
. . . ii  [The r̲i̲c̲h̲] cannot enter the
kingdom of Heaven. . . . Note also the
fused-head restrictive modifier in proper names like Ivan [the
T̲e̲r̲r̲i̲b̲l̲e̲]. Source: The Cambridge Grammar of the
English Language

